# Android Content Provider Cursor Query

Tags: android, mysql, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I am Using Android's builtin Content Provider android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

Now I have

```
String[] sarray  = {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};`
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID , MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
String selection = ?????? // My qestion

cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                    null , order);
```

So how do I write my cursor line so that I select  All BUT NOT `saray` FROM `MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID` column.

Comment: what does **saray** contain? name of the images?

Comment: sarray contains Image _Id, In this question I have used a,b,c to simplify

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] sarray  = {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID , MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    String selection =""+MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID+" !=? AND  "+MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID+"" +
            " !=? AND "+MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID+" !=? AND "+MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID+" !=?";

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,
            sarray , order);
```